# Adding in an int variable inside the onDraw with a class to handle the if statement

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I am trying to insert the current suit but in the form of text near the users current score. I created the following:

```
private int currentSuit = 0;
```

I have entered the following in the onDraw section:

```
canvas.drawText("Suit: " + (currentSuit), 300,
    screenH-whitePaint.getTextSize()-12, whitePaint);
```

Also created the following:

```
    public void currentSuit() {
        String suitText = "";
        if (validSuit == 100) {
            suitText = "Dimonds";
        } else if (validSuit == 200){
            suitText = "Clubs";
        } else if (validSuit == 300){
            suitText = "Hearts";
        } else if (validSuit == 400){
            suitText = "Spades";
        }
    }
```

I am fairly new to coding in java and android. Hopefully someone can shed some light on what I am doing wrong.

I'm currently able to put validSuit but I get the number value of the current suit.

The validSuit comes from the discardPile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your issue is (as you didn't explicitly say the error), but I think you want to rename `currentSuit` to `validSuit`, and instead add the following to onDraw:

```
canvas.drawText("Suit: " + currentSuit(), 300,
    screenH-whitePaint.getTextSize()-12, whitePaint);
```

Comment: Sorry about that I'm currently able to put validSuit but I get the number value of the current suit.

Comment: @Karrbs Sorry, I still don't follow, what exactly is it that you want compared to what is happening?

Comment: Your answer was correct, I needed to change `public void` to `private string` and then I am renaming it to `getCurrentSuit` the using what you recomended.

Comment: @Karbs Great, glad to hear I could help!